# Is the following argument valid?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to determine if the following argument is valid.  Assuming the first four statements are true, can we be assured that $\lnot s \land t$ must also be true.

Here is the argument.

$(1)\quad p \land r$

$(2)\quad \lnot r \lor t$

$(3)\quad s \to \lnot(q)$

$(4) \quad p \to  q$

---

$\therefore \quad \lnot(s) \land t$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Tuth table. Alternatively, assume that the conclusion is *false* and try to find a contradicition.

Comment: I need some tips because I am stuck I tried with a truth table but it's too long. Maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: @user3032175 Too long?  32 rows isn't too bad ...

Comment: But @Bram28, it's not sufficient for the task, or it is certainly inefficient for the task.

Comment: @amWhy inefficient yes ... but clearly sufficient!

Comment: @amWhy A deduction is sufficient, yes, but so is a truth-table ... I don't understand why you say a truth-table is not sufficient for demonstrating validity/invalidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $\quad p \land r$

2) $\quad\lnot r \lor t$

3) $\quad s \to \lnot(q)$

4) $\quad p \to  q$

---

5) $\quad p\quad$ (from premise one), simplification

6) $\quad r\quad$ (from premise one), simplification

7) $\quad\lnot (\lnot r)\quad$ (from 6, Double negation).

8) $\quad \color{blue}{t}\quad$ (from premise 2, and 7: disjunctive syllogism.)

9) $\quad q\quad $ (from 4 and 5, modus ponens)

10) $\quad\lnot (\lnot q)\quad$ (from 9, double negation.)

11) $\quad \color{blue}{\lnot s}\quad$ (from 3, 10, modus tollens.)

$\therefore\;12) \quad\color{blue}{\lnot s \land t}\quad $ (from 11, 8, conjunction introduction).

Therefore, $\lnot s \land t$ follows from the given premises.  That means, if the premises are all true, so is the conclusion.

Comment: The question you want to be asking here is whether the argument, consisting of four premises, and one conclusion, is valid; in other words, that the conclusion (12) logically follows from the initial premises.  It does, so we know that if all the given premises (4) are true, then so is the conclusion.

Comment: The only way to check this via a truth table would be to write the truth table for five variables (2^5 = 32 rows), and evaluating the conjunction of $$\Big((p \land r) \land (\lnot r \lor t) \land (s\to \lnot q) \land (p\to q) \Big)\to (\lnot s \land t)$$ and ensuring it results in a tautology.  In this case, we are given an argument with four premises, and asked to determine if the conclusion validly follows from the premises, such that if all premises are true, the conclusion must also be true.

Answer (score 2):

Using the contrapositive, observe you have

$$\begin{cases}S\to\neg Q\iff Q\to\neg S\\P\to Q\end{cases}$$

and you already get $\;\neg S\;$ .

Since you have $\;P\wedge R\;$ , from $\;\neg R\lor T\;$ it *must* be that $\;T\;$ . Complete the little details left and prove what you want.

Comment: Using a truth table I came to the conclusion that is false. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are...but check carefully your table **and also** my answer. It could perfectly well be I am the wrong one...

Comment: No,, user 3032175, the conclusion follows from the premises.

Comment: @user3032175 If you show your table in the post we can try to figure out where you went wrong ... and you can hopefully learn something from that.